# Functional equation $f(x^2+y^2)=f(x^2-y^2)+2xy \quad \forall\; x,y\in\Bbb R$

Tags: functional-equations

> A double differentiable function satisfies $$f(x^2+y^2)=f(x^2-y^2)+2xy \quad \forall\; x,y\in\Bbb R$$
> Given that $f(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2$, determine $f(x)$.

I tried to convert the equation into some form of Cauchy's additive function by observing that $f(x)$ is an even function. However, I am unable to make any significant progress. Any hints will be appreciated.

**Edit**: My apologies for posting the incorrect question. Correct question:

> $$f(x^2+y^2)=f(x^2-y^2)+f(2xy) \quad \forall\; x,y\in\Bbb R$$
> Given that $f(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2$, determine $f(x)$.

This has already been answered here [Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty)$such that $f(x^2 + y^2)=f(x^2 - y^2)+ f(2xy)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607339/find-all-functions-f-mathbbr-to-0-inftysuch-that-fx2-y2-fx2#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function. Putting $x=y$ we get $f(2x^{2})=2x^{2}$ which implies that $f(t)=t$ for all  $t \geq 0$. Since $f$ is also even (as seen by putting $x=0$) we get $f(t)=|t|$ which is not even differentiable.

Comment: Even if the additional assumptions of (double) differentiability, $ f ( 0 ) = 0 $ and $ f '' ( 0 ) = 2 $ were dropped, the functional equation itself would give us $ f ( x ) = f ( 0 ) + | x | $ by your method. Putting this back into the functional equation gives
$$ f ( 0 ) + x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 = f ( 0 ) + \left | x ^ 2 - y ^ 2 \right | + 2 x y \text , $$
or equivalently
$$ ( x - y ) ^ 2 = \left | x ^ 2 - y ^ 2 \right | $$
for all real number $ x $ and $ y $, which doesn't hold for cases as simple as $ x = 2 $ and $ y = 1 $. So, there is no function even only satisfying the functional equation.